# Dynamodb modeling time and location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Can you provide me some solution how to medel event table using dynamodb.

My event table must provide informacion about startDate, endDate, location (latitude,longitude, city, postcode, country), name, description, photo, owner, eventType ... .

Users can search all event at a distance of 50 kilometers from them, startDate and eventType.

I havent got any idea how model that domain using dynamodb.

Thanks for any response :)

Answer (score 1):

May be worth taking a look at [Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB - Part 1: Table Structure](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxWTJOSLE7O3J2/Geo-Library-for-Amazon-DynamoDB-Part-1-Table-Structure)

Which discuss the [geo library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo) for DynamoDB.

You may also be able to prepend the startDate in the range key if you are doing something like "get events that have a startDate > X". Or prepend the eventType and use BEGINS_WITH for equality conditions.